# How to get user's first name or last name from @context.User?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, active-directory, blazor, asp.net-authorization

I created a Server side Blazor application using Windows authentication. And it created the following file.

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
<AuthorizeView>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
</AuthorizeView>
```

However, it shows "DOMAIN\username". Is it a way to show the user first name?

I tried to print all the claim types.

```
@foreach(var c in context.User.Claims)
{
    <p>@c.Value @c.Type</p>
}
```

However, there is only one type with name in it. (with value of `DOMAIN\username`)

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go out to AD for that information. But connecting to AD in ASP.NET Core isn't straight-forward.

If you are only going to run this on a Windows server, then you can install `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` from NuGet, and use `DirectoryEntry` to bind directly to the object using its SID. The SID is available in `context.User.Identity.User.Value`.

```
<AuthorizeView>
@{
    var identity = (WindowsIdentity) context.User.Identity;
    var user = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://<SID={identity.User.Value}>");

    //Add any other attributes you want to read to this list
    user.RefreshCache(new [] { "givenName" });
}
    Hello, @user.Properties["givenName"].Value!
</AuthorizeView>
```

Other attributes you might be interested in:

- `sn`: Last name
- `displayName`: How their name is displayed in Outlook, for example. Often this is "Last, First"

Comment: It shows the error of `The name 'context' does not exists in the current context` for `context.User.Identity.User.Value`.

Comment: You used `context` in your own code.... That should be your `HttpContext`, however you are able to get at it.

Comment: Also turns out you need to cast the `IIdentity` to a `WindowsIdentity`. I updated my code.

Comment: Tried your updated answer. But it still got the error. Strangely, it works in `@context` and `@foreach` block. But not in `@{ ... }`. (I put it right before my `@foreach` block.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Yes, it's a server side Blazor application. I should be .Net core 3.0. The `@context` is an implicit parameter according to enet's answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you need to use `Context` (upper-case C). But `DirectoryEntry` is not available by default in ASP.NET Core. It's only available in the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` NuGet package, which only works if you are only going to run this on Windows.

Comment: Changed `context` to `Context` and still got the same error.

Comment: Maybe the code block needs to be inside the [`AuthorizeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component) component, since it looks like that is what exposes `context`. (I haven't had any experience with Blazor yet.)

Comment: Yes, it need to be inside of `AuthorizeView` and only lowercase `context` works.

Comment: I found that `user.RefreshCache(new [] { "givenName" });` is not required. I forgot to change the parameter string and it still works.

Comment: This is not Blazor, and a nonsensical answer. The ClaimsPrincipal object should be provided by the AuthrenticationStateProvider...

Comment: @ca9163d9 It's not required, but if you omit it, then the first time you use `.Properties` it will retrieve every attribute with a value, which is a bunch of data you aren't going to use.

Comment: @enet I didn't realize this was Blazor when I first posted this answer. It may not be the best way, but it's clearly not "nonsensical" if it works. Feel free to post your own answer. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use it as below using the Directory Services (install using NuGet).

**_Imports.razor**

```
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
<AuthorizeView>
    @{
        var pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XYZ.net", "DC=XYZ,DC=net");
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcontext, context.User.Identity.Name);
    }    
    Hello, @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname!
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this in blazor web assembly. and API using asp.net core 6 and its works as i expected
here is the code

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname,user.LastName)

        };
```

I just return the Name with Firstname then +"give space here"+ give Lastname

and it gives me results using

@context.User.Identity.Name

Hi! You're logged in with Vikas Admin.

Admin is the last name of the user.

Thankyou